# Dim recessed lights

Tags: lighting, recessed-lighting

I've got a problem with two recessed lights in the hallway that come on dim when switched on.  No other lights are connected to these two.  Two three way switches (*non-dimmer*) control these two lights and each displays the same problem.

The circuit breaker to these lights are the same as the garage light which is okay.  At both switches I measured about 112v while the switch was off.  When I flipped the switch on voltage read about 10v at both switches.

I find it unlikely that both switches are bad but maybe.  Is the voltage reading suppose to read 0 when switched on.  The bulbs are flood light types.  The switches are different, one has one hot, neutral and ground connected to it.  The other has two hot, neutral and one ground. These lights/switches are the original from when I first moved in 5 years, no changes to these assys.

What could be the problem?

*Yes I've checked the bulbs at another location and their fine. I'm a newbie so bear with me if I've left anything out.*

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would wonder if the two sockets got wired in series.  Easy way to check:  Turn them on and then unscrew one bulb.  If both go out they're wired in series.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?

Comment: Is there any thing new about the wiring or switches here? Can you give it a try with real incandescent bulbs?

Comment: Are the bulbs incandescent, CFL ord LED?

Comment: The bulbs are incandescent.